# Override method of the class that inside the function

Tags: javascript, include, javascript-objects, prototype, extends

I have the below structure in file a.js

```
function factory() {
    class A {
        constructor() {
            
        }

        add(num) {
            return num + 1;
        }
    }

    return A;
}
```

I would like to change the behavior of the "add" method. "add" method would look like below. Addition of 2 instead of 1.

```
add(num) {
    return num + 2;
}
```

I have created a new file name as b.js

```
const a = import("a.js");
(new factory()).prototype.add = function(num) {
    return num + 2;
}
```

But it does not change the behavior of the add method inside the "factory" function(a.js file). I would like to change the behavior of the "add" method of the "factory" function(a.js), Could you please provide help or guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `factory` function will create and return a *new* class.

So adding the `add` method on the prototype of a class returned by the particular call to `factory` function will have no effect on the classes returned by other calls to the `factory` function.

Following demo shows how you can achieve the desired result.

```js
function factory() {
  class A {
    add(num) {
      return num + 1;
    }
  }

  return A;
}

const MyClass = factory();

MyClass.prototype.add = function (num) {
  return num + 2;
};

const b = new MyClass();
console.log(b.add(1));
```

If you call the `factory` function again, it will return a new class which will have the `add` method that adds only 1.

Following demo shows this in action:

```js
function factory() {
  class A {
    add(num) {
      return num + 1;
    }
  }

  return A;
}

const MyClassA = factory();
const MyClassB = factory();

// Overwrite "add" method in MyClassA
MyClassA.prototype.add = function (num) {
  return num + 2;
};

console.log(new MyClassA().add(1)); // 3
console.log(new MyClassB().add(1)); // 2 (MyClassB uses the defaul "add" method)
```

So, you will need to add the `add` method in the prototype every time `factory` function is called.

---

One way to avoid overwriting the `add` method everytime you call `factory` function is to create another function, that:

1. Calls the `factory` function
2. Updates the `add` method
3. Returns the class with the updated `add` method

With this approach, code that overwrites the `add` method is re-usable.

Following code shows an example:

```js
function factory() {
  class A {
    add(num) {
      return num + 1;
    }
  }

  return A;
}

function factoryWrapper() {
  const MyClass = factory();

  MyClass.prototype.add = function(num) {
    return num + 2;
  };
  
  return MyClass;
}

const Class1 = factoryWrapper();
const Class2 = factoryWrapper();

console.log(new Class1().add(1));
console.log(new Class2().add(1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

"If you call the factory function again, it will return a new class which will have the add method that adds only 1." - This would not expected behavior.

I would like to change main factory's add method behavior.
I can't update the add method in a.js because this is core file of the framework. The may update anytime. That's why I would like to change the add method behavior globally without make the change to core file.

Comment: Then you can do what is shown in the answer. Get a class by calling the `factory` function; overwrite its `add` method; use that particular class everywhere. See the updated answer.